# Groovy List of domain object not saved and not sorted in controller

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a groovy domain class. Fields are not mapped to database. 
Controller creates a list of such object and sort it before send to the view.

```
instances = instances.sort() { it.part_number }
```

It didn't sort. And print members of the list returns 0 for integer field, null for String field.

Printing the first element

```
println instances[0]
```

resulted in

```
mypackage.Order : (unsaved)
```

Why it is unsaved? And not sortable?

It would work if I move my domain class to src/groovy as POGO class. But only when I declareed part_number as String. If part_number is Integer. It would crash.

```
| Error 2015-01-15 09:17:14,771 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - GroovyCastException occurred when processing request: [GET] myapp/showInstances - parameters:
sort: part_number
order: asc
Cannot cast object '259042' with class 'groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren' to class 'java.lang.Integer'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot cast object '259042' with class 'groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren' to class 'java.lang.Integer'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mypackage.Order : (unsaved)` is the result of the implementation of `toString()` that Grails adds to domain classes - it's the full class name with package and the `id`, or the string `(unsaved)` if it's not a persistent instance. But other than telling you the class name and that there's no id, it doesn't indicate *anything* about the contents of other fields and properties.

The list is very likely sorted, but you're not displaying relevant data from that instance. Try this instead:

```
println instances[0].dump()
```

or more directly

```
println instances[0].part_number
```

Also consider implementing a `toString()` method that displays class data, e.g.

```
String toString() {
   part_number
}
```

Note that Grails domain classes abuse the "domain" concept a bit and are always persistent. If you have a POGO class that you want to use as part of your application domain (in the general sense) those should be in `src/groovy` (or POJOs in `src/java`). When you change to that, there won't be any Grails-added `toString()` method so you'll get the default implementation that all classes get (e.g. something like `mypackage.Order@48c02bce`, the class name with package and hashCode value in hex form)

*EDIT - update based on updated question*

Your XML parsing code is bad. You're storing a `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren` instance which has a `toString()` result of `"259042"`, but that's neither an Integer nor a String - just an object with data that can be converted to both. The reason it works when you define the property type as `String` is that anything can be stored by Groovy in a String property - it just calls `toString()` on it. But there's no support in Groovy for automagically converting a `NodeChildren` instance that happens to have a stringified number to that number - you need to do that yourself. That's independent of the sorting issue though, so that would need to be discussed in a separate question.

Comment: You are correct. Once I converted that field to String and create Integer object, it started working. And it is a separate issue. Anyway, it is working now. Thanks!